# Can AutoMapper call a method on destination for each member of collection on source?

Tags: automapper

I have two classes as below.

```
public class Destination
{
   public Destination()
   {
      _StringCollection = new List<String>();
   }
   private ICollection<String> _StringCollection;
   public IEnumerable<String> StringCollection
   {
     get
     {
       return _StringCollection.AsEnumerable<String>();
     }
   }

   public void AddString(string str)
   {
      _StringCollection.Add(str);
   }
 }

 public class Source
 {
    public List<String> StringCollection { get; set; }
 }
```

I would like to map that for each member of source call AddString(member) on Destination.

I thought that maybe I could do something with a custom resolver but can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: I think this could help you http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @Omu that looks pretty interesting, I'll have to check it out when I have some extra time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't redirect to a specific method.  You can expose as an ICollection, but that's it.